# Acceleration in a vacuum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

If a body has constant velocity in a vacuum it doesn't slow down. So if a body has acceleration in a vacuum does it gain velocity forever.

Comment: How does the body in a vacuum accelerate? What is exerting a force on it to make it accelerate?

Comment: A single body in vacuum does not accelerate. It takes at least two bodies to accelerate each other.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! It is recommended in order to avoid downvotes show some info that you have already sought answers to by other means (eg. web search) and  add some context to your question (like what other facts that cause you to question this)

Answer (score 1):

You accelerate an object by applying a force to it. so, in your example, the object would experience a force (say for instance by a rocket engine), and therefore continue accelerating for as long as the force on it persists.

This ignores relativistic effects about which more can be written if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example a meteor falling straight towards the Earth will accelerate until it hits the atmosphere.  A ship with a working propulsion system (say electric propulsion) can accelerate indefinitely until its fuel runs out.

If it accelerates to near light speed, although it continues to accelerate and never stops, it's speed will gradually approach the speed of light, but never reach it.